# Number of shards in Solr

Tags: solr, indexing, sharding

We are expecting indexes to be created for 6TB of data. Index size would be around 10 GB . 
1) So how many shards are required?
2) Because of the hardware limitation I'm thinking to use only 1 Solr machine with number of shards. I have 16GB RAM and 4 core machine.

Kindly let me know your experience on this.

Answer (score 1):

If your index size is nothing more than 10GB and all the shards would be living on one single server, there isn't much reason to consider sharding at this time. It will probably not give you much either way. If you're planning on adding more servers later, you can distribute your index at that time - when you have an idea of what kind of resources you'll have available. You probably want to look into SolrCloud in that case - handling both replicas and sharding transparently.

For now, if on a single server, you can use a single server and do replication if needed for a second server for a larger query load.

It's more important to have a good and easy process for re-indexing data than doing everything way scaled out at the beginning.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong....as I'm using single machine then I should use replication to other solr instance within the same box. In this case how many instance are required to replicate conserding my size of index? Also, is it possible to do replication when using sharding?

Comment: Replication will replicate a single shard to another instance, so that's not an issue. If you're going to do sharding _and_ replication already, you probably want to do SolrCloud from the start.

Answer (score 0):

As always it depends on the queries you will be running and the data. I suggest spending a bit of time and testing various configurations to see which one provides the best value.

One thing to consider is that you will probably require HA, as such a second server is required, however it all depends on your requirements.

I have four 10 gb shards running on a single box, with 32 GB allocated to the JVM and they perform fine. They are also mirrored with SolrCloud to another instance (so queries get distributed between them). We usually get about 250k queries a day and use a lot of faceting and a few functions in each one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the numbers, when you mirrored to another instance then those mirrored instance are within same box or different box? how much is the total index size in your application and which storage drive you have used?

Comment: the replicas are on a different box for HA. total index size is arounf 45GB, 200k queries day. not sure on the drives, but most of that index is in linux memory cache anyway